# How do I fix the prompt ending with an asterisk sign without exiting hbase shell?

Tags: hbase

I know the commands in hbase shell need not end with a ';'.
In hbase shell, typing commands end with a ';' or incorrect characters would change the end of the prompt from '>' to an asterisk sign.
For example:

```
describe 'some_table';
```

or

```
"using right-key to copy text from putty"
```

The end of the prompt will change to an asterisk sign after running this command.
[image]
This stops me from typing other commands.
How do I fix the prompt ending with an asterisk sign without exiting hbase shell?

```
/* edit my question    
Ctrl+D can stop an incomplete command in hbase shell.    
*/
```

Comment: Hello, @Julia, I am also relatively new to Stack Overflow, but it seems you have found the answer to your question, in this kind of situation you should probably answer your own question, which in this case you added in an edit inside the question. You can also accept the answer as solved. Thank you for the information though, it solved my problem :)  

("Ctrl+D can stop an incomplete command in hbase shell. ") quoted from your question

Comment: Also, I've recently learned HBase's shell is based on a ruby shell, and some ruby commands did in fact work on it, so a nice thing to know for HBase beginners.